# Issue with Web Application and ISA Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, isaserver

right now this code works by picking up the authenticated user (windows authentication). we are using active directory. however if you are off the network and try to log into this specific application you get redirected to our ISA 2006 server, which then passes login information into the application (in theory, lol)

when I access this app on my phone over 3g its pretty slow, but i dont get an error (the error just being a popup with an ok button, sometimes it says error, sometimes it doesnt). However when I use a faster better computer over the external it does give me this error. Unit testing by my colleagues revealed there to be some sort of recursive loop or some sort which was giving the error. any time you log into the web application while on the network, it picks up windows authentication with no problem and gives no error. I have spent 3 days trying to figure out my bug but cant find it, I hope another few set of eyes can help me track it down (I am using ASP.net 4.0 with C#)

```
public string IdentifyUser()
    {
        string retval = string.Empty;
        try{


               //System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
                //string UserIdentityName = p.Identity.Name;
                string UserIdentityName = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
                //string UserIdentityName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                string slash = @"\";
                string Username = UserIdentityName.Substring(UserIdentityName.IndexOf(slash) + 1);
                retval = Data_Access_Layers.SQL.GetUserID(Username);




           }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

basically this fires off, pulls the username, it gets sent to "GetUserID" which looks up that username and sends back the user id attached to that person, which is then sent back out to the main page, and is stored in a javascript variable (to be used on other parts of the page)

Comment: Here is GetUserID just in case... but really that one is just a simple SQL query


       public static string GetUserID(string Username)
        {
            string retval = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                retval = ExecCmdScalar("SELECT ID FROM Users Where Username = '" + Username + "'", CommandType.Text, null).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return retval;
        }

Comment: The reason for all the commented out variations is due to trying to track down the bug, all of those methods work internally..lol, aint coding fun

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that AUTH_USER is empty?

What is the value of the AUTH_TYPE header when accessing the app from inside and outside the network?

Comment: from inside the network (and using the debugger) it pulls back my own information correctly, im not tied to any one method really.

internally everything works, but externally the user goes to our page, gets redirected to ISA to log in, that information should be passed in, and according to my manager it shouldnt matter, that code should pull whatever it is from either location... and yet its not.

Comment: the value of AUTH_TYPE internally is NTLM

Comment: Well, I'm new to this, lol. Hoping to have this figured out soon, probably end up rewriting the entire authentication code.

Comment: ISA Server has a set of configurable rules on whether it forwards authentication information. But still I don't see how AUTH_USER could ever be empty if your web application is requiring authentication.

Comment: So I'd like to update here... Turns out a combination of AT&T and google was causing an issue here. The web app uses google maps and we tracked this down to their end by having both of our directors uses their devices on a multitude of mobile hotspots (Verizon, sprint, AT&T) and they could never log into the app while on AT&T network, even though the auth code works like a champ when they get off att lol. So let this be a lesson apparently this is a known bug bwtweeb att and google maps